# Reading pdf on ipad using stageWebView in adobe air

Tags: air

I am using stageWebView is flash CC to open a pdf in an air for ios app.

Is there a way to tell the browser to read one page at a time, and autosize each page to full screen?

Currently it shows the pdf scrolling and as such the page sizes vary constantly.

Many thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You cannot communicate with `StageWebView` in any way whatsoever outside of telling it to load a page, go back, go forward, and reload the page. Beyond that, there is zero communication between the AS3 and the actual web page.

Even if there was, though, I do not think you could do what you want. This is the built-in iOS PDF viewer you are using. There would be no sense in Apple allowing a page to alter how it behaves when it is only loading a PDF (as opposed to a webpage with JS and CSS)

Comment: OK, so can it be controlled through wrapping it in a web page and using css

Comment: I sincerely doubt it. The PDF display mechanism *is not* a web page. It is an app/plugin that is run in the browser to display the file. I do not believe you can embed PDFs. Regardless, as I said, there would be no point in Apple giving you control over this so it is extremely unlikely that they did. I genuinely think you are out of luck here. What you want just is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have alook on [PDF.js](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/) it is HTML5 library to view pdf (it may help you to control what to view from the PDF), i didn't try it...